# Work with the result of re.findall()

Tags: python, regex

I am using Pandoc to transform HTML into LaTeX. It works pretty well, yet I would like to post-process the output to fit my needs. Consider the following output :

```
string = r'foo\r\nbar\r\n\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}ll@{}}\r\nbar & bar\tabularnewline\r\nbar & bar\r\n\bottomrule\r\n\end{longtable}'
```

What I need to do is to capture the alignment of the tabular (the `c` option, the column configuration, and the content of the tabular. Here is what I have done so far :

```
tabular_setup = re.findall(r'\\begin{longtable}\[(.*)\]{(.*)}(.*)\\end{longtable}', string, re.DOTALL)

if tabular_setup:
    tabular_align = tabular_setup[0][0]
    column_setup  = tabular_setup[0][1]
    tab_content   = tabular_setup[0][2]
```

So now I can update those values to whatever value I want, but then, how to I update those value in the original string ?

Comment: whihc group you want to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def repl(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group(1):
        return "1" #something
    if matchobj.group(2):
        return "1" #something 

new=re.sub(r"\\begin{longtable}\[(.*)\]{(.*)}(.*)\\end{longtable}",repl,string)
```

You can update the groups using `re.sub` and your own `replacement function`.

Comment: Thank you, yet your `repl()` method takes an argument, and you don't pass it in your `sub()` call

Comment: @EddaSnorra it gets passed implicitly

Comment: @EddaSnorra it is working.You need to return a string which i have not done in exmaple provided as i dont know what replacements you want to make